# PHP upload large image error, small size image works fine

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Hi guys i am using the code from [w3school php fileupload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) but when upload some image that bigger than 2000+ kb and come out the error. **Upload small size photo works fine.**
anyone know whats the problem?
I checked the code and there is file size limit condition but havent reach there and the code is die.
**Test or View code here >>> [sample](https://replit.com/@YenKai/test-upload#index.php)**

[image]

```
html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

```
php
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  echo "<pre>";
  var_export($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
  echo "</pre>";
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); //get error at here
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try check the php.ini, search for upload_max_filesize, check if the filesize is larger than you needed.
The default is usually smaller.

Comment: checked there are 2M filesize

Comment: 2000kb = 2Mb, so try change it to 10M to upload something 2000+kb